# Error editing Default Organization Address in CiviCRM 5.2.2

Tags: drupal

we are running CiviCRM 5.2.2 on a Drupal 7 website

We need to edit the organization address information.

In CiviCRM, find ADMINISTER: COMMUNICATIONS: ORGANIZATION ADDRESS and CONTACT INFO
https://dama.org/civicrm/admin/domain?action=update&reset=1

This opens an editor where you can change the DEFAULT ORGANIZATION ADDRESS.

But when I change the address and try to save it, I get the following error:

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
>   moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
>   with more details about what action you were performing when this
>   occurred. DB Error: unknown error Error Details Return to home page.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Here is the backtrace for the error:

```
#0 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(190): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "\n    CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER ...")
#4 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "\n    CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER ...")
#5 [internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "\n    CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(224): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:8))
#7 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#8 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "\n    CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#9 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1419 ** You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (yo...")
#10 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#11 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("\n    CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER ...")
#12 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2443): DB_common->query("\n    CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER ...")
#13 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1635): DB_DataObject->_query("\n    CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER ...")
#14 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(415): DB_DataObject->query("\n    CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER ...")
#15 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1371): CRM_Core_DAO->query("\n    CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER ...", FALSE)
#16 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/SqlTriggers.php(225): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\n    CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER ...", (Array:0), TRUE, NULL, FALSE, FALSE)
#17 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(3438): Civi\Core\SqlTriggers->enqueueQuery("\n    CREATE FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER ...")
#18 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/SqlTriggers.php(62): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::triggerInfo((Array:5), NULL)
#19 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(2092): Civi\Core\SqlTriggers->rebuild(NULL, FALSE)
#20 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(2107): CRM_Core_DAO::triggerRebuild()
#21 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Phone.php(74): CRM_Core_DAO::checkSqlFunctionsExist()
#22 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Block.php(348): CRM_Core_BAO_Phone::add((Array:8))
#23 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Location.php(66): CRM_Core_BAO_Block::create("phone", (Array:12), NULL)
#24 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Domain.php(248): CRM_Core_BAO_Location::create((Array:12), TRUE)
#25 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(453): CRM_Contact_Form_Domain->postProcess()
#26 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#27 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Domain), "next", "Next")
#28 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Domain), "next")
#29 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Domain), "next")
#30 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#31 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#32 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(283): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Contact_Form_Domain", "Organization Address and Contact Info", NULL)
#33 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:17))
#34 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#35 /home/forge/dama.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#36 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("admin", "domain")
#37 /home/forge/dama.org/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#38 /home/forge/dama.org/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#39 {main}
```

Let me know if you have any insight into what's wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 2):

In number 9 it says "You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled". Your mysql user doesn't have enough privileges.